# sliding drawer with content below it

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am having a sliding drawer positioned at the bottom . and below that I have a linear layout of 50dp .

So my layout looks like this :

[image]

Where red rectangle is the sliding drawer handle

Now when I slide my finger from bottom of the screen to the sliding drawer , i.e. along the blue path

[image]

The sliding drawer doesn't open . It doesn't open because the click activity is captured by the bottom layout.
The sliding drawer opens only when I click EXACTLY within the red rectangle.

I tried making the bottom layout clickable=>false focussable=>false still no good.

Any idea on how can I make the click event of bottom layout loose its click as soon as the finger is out of the layout ? , so that the handle can capture the click

Comment: dont think anything could help you coz, you need both click-able right?. Then better, you adjust the size of red rectangle. there are some events but its regarding to touch not click. i.e ondispatchtouchevent().

Comment: I don't need the bottom layer clcikable.. since I can always use relative layout/ framelayout and place the button separately .

Comment: adjusting the heght doesn't work .. because there is no user who would click on the handle even if it is 100dp since everybody slides from the bottom

Comment: why dont you try to put something on left corner like image button as handler displaying up marker as the applications screen from the launcher of android 2.1?

Comment: Designs fixed.. :( I am a dev :D

Comment: k what a developer could do either..:D

Comment: better try with WAQAS' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to create the entire linear layout (brown bottom bar) as *handler* for your drawer. Doing so will allow you to slide the drawer as you want in the second picture.

Or, alternatively, you can make use of FrameLayout to present LinearLayout and drawer's view as with in a single layout and set the width and height of your drawer as linear layout - covering the entire area of linear layout.

Or, at last, implement *SimpleOnGestureListener* on linearlayout (for upwards direction) to execute drawer's click action.

Comment: but in that case the bottom bar would also move up which I don't want

Comment: see my updated answer. then perhaps you need to implement SimpleOnGestureListener listener on your linear layout to emulate drawer's click action

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried clickable=false and focusable=false... did you also set focusableintouchmode=false? (I would set all three and see what happens).

As I painfully discovered recently, focusable-false only covers the hardware, not the touch screen.  I had to add focusableintouchmode="false".. maybe that will work for you too.